# Azure DocumentDB, In SP, setTimeout throw exception

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

In Azure DocumentDB, running the next SP

```
function sample(prefix) { 
    setTimeout(function() { throw "gg"; }, "1000"); 
}
```

Throw the next exception

> Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception =
>   ReferenceError: 'setTimeout' is undefined

Is there no way to use setTimeout in DocumentDB ?

Comment: You can refer to http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/, the documentdb server sdk hasn't support timeout functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout is not supported, but you shouldn't need it. The engine will stay alive until all pending async operations have either returned or timed out.

If you provide us with more code, we may be able to show you how to do what you are doing without setTimeout.